# Images Not Scaling & Centering

Tags: css, image

OK, I have scanned the forums trying to find a solution to my dilemma and have tried everything I found. If someone could please take a look at the following URL: [angrybullhartford](http://angrybullhartford.com)

When I resize any browser, the problems seem to differ a little, The two images in the right sidebar do not center and scale to a tiny size. The slider at the top of the page is small and off center as well. I had this working at one point and cannot get back to it. If it is something simple and someone could tell me why this is occurring I would appreciate it.
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is some sort of left margin or padding on the slider.  It does not line up with the elements below it.  When you start to make the page smaller, you can really see this margin I'm talking about.

Anyhow, try this:  Change your CSS to

```
 #page .pad {
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
 }
```

This produced a much cleaner result for me, not sure if it's exactly what you want though.  Being that you're using BS2, you may have to write some media queries to handle your extra styles.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I am a bit swamped now but  Iwill give it a try in the am and let you know. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I just started from scratch with the whole project and things came out right. I must have screwed up somewhere along the way. I appreciate the help. Thanks again:-)